# If i am the first coauthor of the paper, is it possible to change the order of names on the paper in my resume?

Tags: publications, cv, authorship, formatting

If i am the first coauthor of the paper, is it possible to change the order of names on the paper in my resume and show my name on the first place?

Comment: It seems a little passive aggressive (at least to me). I am not sure that I'd recommend it.

Comment: I think being about "co-first author" makes this different from the possible duplicate. (The answer is the same, but the question is different.)

Comment: I'm glad you've asked this question, which you were unsure about, so I'm voting the question up.

Answer (score 14):

Since you write that you are co-first author, I assume you are from a discipline where authorship order matters (e.g. life sciences), and then the answer is **NO**. In fact, this may be seen as purposeful misleading.

The authorship order is essentially part of the paper and how it is indexed.

And if authorship order in your field does not matter, why would you want to do this?

Comment: Even in disciplines where author order isn't important (e.g. some areas in pure mathematics and theoretical computer science) it isn't appropriate to change the order around.  You want the CV to include proper citations that the reader can match to search in online databases and journals, and having a different author order makes it look as though you're talking about a different paper.

Answer (score 7):

Do not change the order as it appears on the publication.  If you are officially a co-first author, by some declaration in the paper or elsewhere, such as an * with the comment that 'these authors contributed equally, you can do the same on your Resume by having a * claiming you are a co-first author.